# CPTScatterPlot not showing

Tags: ipad, ios-simulator, core-plot, scatter-plot

I am using CPTScatterPlot for showing graphs in iPad. The code runs properly but the points are not plotted on the graph. Not even a single point is shown. Why is it so???

My code is:

```
CPTScatterPlot *dataSourceLinePlot = [[[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init] autorelease];
dataSourceLinePlot.identifier = @"Red Plot";

CPTMutableLineStyle *symbolLineStyle2 = [CPTLineStyle lineStyle];
symbolLineStyle2.lineColor = [CPTColor redColor];
symbolLineStyle2.lineWidth = 5.0;
//symbolLineStyle2.miterLimit = 1.0f;
dataSourceLinePlot.dataLineStyle = symbolLineStyle2;
dataSourceLinePlot.dataSource = self;
[graph addPlot:dataSourceLinePlot];


// Animate in the new plot, as an example
dataSourceLinePlot.opacity = 0.0f;
[graph addPlot:dataSourceLinePlot];
```

I checked both the delegate methods. Both return proper values but graph is not plotted what could be the reason. Please help...

Comment: Don't add the same plot to the graph more than once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this line:

```
dataSourceLinePlot.opacity = 0.0f;
```

Comment: Your suggestion was right but my main problem was i didn't entered the x-y axis range properly...